# what is the best way to create a criteria filter?

Tags: grails

I have the following domain class

```
class Something {
  User user
  BigDecimal balance
  Boolean cancelled
  String status
  Client client
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

  static constraints { ... }

  ...
}
```

I need to create a filter to this domain class the ui looks like this

[image]

I do not know how to create this filter all its criteria are optionals so I need your suggestions about what is the best way to create a criteria filter?

Thanks

Comment: You can use multiple `if` blocks inside the criteria query based on corresponding element's availability?

Comment: I did not know that i can use ifs inside criteria. That help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this

```
List<Something filter(Client client, String status, BigDecimal balance) (
  Something.withCriteria {

    if (client) {
      eq 'client', client
    }    

    if (status) {
      eq 'status', status 
    }    

    if (balance != null) {
      eq 'balance', balance 
    }    

    // other predicates go here....   
  }
}
```

Comment: The way that is written, be careful about unintended behavior related to Groovy truth.  For example, if `balance` is 1, the `eq 'balance', balance` criteria will be executed but if `balance` is 0 it will not.  If your intent is to query for all `Something` that have a `balance` of 0, that code would not work.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks, I've updated the code to avoid this issue